# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding?

Tags: xml, utf-8, stack-overflow

I have a xml file including 2 million observations that I want to convert to csv, but I get the error below.

```
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 609, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResult
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
File "input/stackoverflow.com/Posts.xml", line 9 lxml.etree.XML
SyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xFC 0x74 0xFC 0x70, line 9, column 360
```

I have included the encoding= "utf-8" but I'm not sure what is the source of this error. Can anyone please help ?

I tried the code below as well and it gives me similar error for encoding.

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
etree.fromstring(filename, parser=parser)

error: xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 9, column 359
```

Comment: Well, what’s the file *actually* encoded in? Apparently it’s *not* UTF-8.

Comment: Without examining the file, we can't tell you what the correct encoding is.  We don't need the *whole* file, just a few of the lines that have characters that aren't decoding in UTF-8. Specifically, at least the line that causes the error (line 9, column 360).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove that error by adding the encoding= 'latin1' and change my code a little bit.

```
context = etree.iterparse(sourcefilename, events=('end',), tag='row',encoding= "latin1"
```

However, I'm facing another issue

lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 26451, column 2887

apparently it is because of having some invalid characters which I don't know how I should replace them.

Comment: Note that `latin1` encoding never fails because a Unicode codepoint is assigned to every possible single byte (0-255).  It will still assign the wrong codepoint if the file encoding is not `latin1`.  Without seeing the file, we can't give you a better option.